# Reparenting a branch in TFS2008

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

Say I have branch A in TFS from which I take branch B. Some changesets are made on B, then from B, branch C is taken, and more changes are made on branch C

```
A ------------------------------
     |
B    ----1--2------------------
                 |
C                ----3-----4---
```

Now suppose we want to merge from C into A, but bypassing B. TFS won't allow this - I have to do a baseless merge, which can be very error prone. Really, I want to get C "reparented" (if that is the correct terminology) so it is a child of A, not B. In other words, I want to end up with the following branch structure. (C' can either be the original C branch, or a new branch that is what C should have been).

```
A ------------------------------
     |   |
B    |   ----1--2------------------
     |           
C'   |-------1--2----3-----4---
```

Now C' can be merged correctly into A without going into B.

My question is, is there any automated tool / script that could set up the pending changes required to create the C' branch, as to manually do this would take us a very long time?

Comment: Why you think the baseless merge is error prone?

Comment: baseless merge results in hundreds of merge "conflicts", including files that were only changed on one of the two branches. this is because it doesn't know the relationship between the branches it is merging. It also doesn't cope with deleted code - the merge puts it back in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reparenting a branch in TFS is hard.  You can effectively give it an additional parent via baseless merge, but:

- baseless merges are tedious & error prone, as you know
- there is no command or API for removiong the merge relationship with the "real" parent, short of Destroy
- you will not be able to perform merges in the new direction via the VS 2005/2008 Merge Wizard

What you seem to be asking for -- and I agree is the best solution -- is a brand new branch named C' that happens to have the same contents that C does today.  Here's a quick way to achieve that:

1. Use the normal Branch dialog to create the new branch.  If it must have the same name as C, that's ok, just rename C to C_old first.  You'll need to decide whether it's appropriate to branch from Latest or from some older version of A.  (If it helps, you can see the version that B was branched from in the Properties dialog.)
2. Delete the new C directory from disk.
3. Navigate a command prompt to the C_old directory, then run **tfpt scorch -diff -deletes**.  This will ensure C_old is up to date and does not contain any extraneous files (e.g. build artifacts).
4. Copy C_old -> C.
5. Navigate to C, then run **tfpt online -adds -deletes -diffs . -r**.  This will pend adds, edits, & deletes as necessary for the server to record the delta between A [as branched] and C [as represented on disk].
6. Checkin

The only disadvantage of this method is that you won't see changes 3 & 4 in the history.  They'll still be under C_old, of course, but tools like Annotate won't know that -- they'll see those changes as occurring all at once, on the date you created C', without the individual comments/work items/etc.

Comment: great answer, thanks. we just soldiered on with fixing the baseless merge conflicts this time, but the the tfpt online command looks like it could be a very useful one to remember for future.

Comment: To be clear, it seems that this technique would need to be used every time you want to merge to the new stream.